# Results from Integrate not matching NIntegrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, symbolic

I am interested in getting a *completely-symbolic* form of an integral of an expression. But I noticed that when I compare my symbolic integral with a numerically calculated integral, I see that there is a substantial difference.

When I integrate my expression, I get a very clean result, but with a very complicated `Condition` attached to it, which looks like this (code provided at end):

[image: image of expression]

I am interpreting that this integral "blows up" for some very complicated situation, but otherwise has a single solution. Now if I grab that solution and plot the real and imaginary parts as a function of the variable $\Delta_p$, I observe that the analytical solution disagrees with its numerical counterpart.

The plots of the real part of the analytic integral vs the numerical integral seems to be pretty close:
[image: real parts of analytical vs numerical integrals]

But the imaginary part of the analytic integral vs the numerical integral have opposite signs:

[image: imaginary parts of analytical vs numerical integrals]

The imaginary part is flipped! Any ideas what is going on? Why is this issue happening?

Here is my code for obtaining these results:

```
expr = 1/W Sqrt[Log[2]/π] 1/(
   1 + (Δ/
     W)^2) (I (-4 (Δ + Δc1)^2 + 
        4 (Δ + Δc1) (Δ + Δc2) + 
        2 γ (Γ + 
           2 I (-Δ + Δc1 - Δc2 - Δp)) + 
        2 I Γ (Δc1 - Δp) + 
        8 (Δ + Δc1) (Δ + Δp) - 
        4 (Δ + Δc2) (Δ + Δp) - 
        4 (Δ + Δp)^2 + Ωc2^2))/(2 γ (Γ + 
         2 I (-Δ + Δc1 - Δc2 - Δp)) (Γ - 
         2 I (Δ + Δp)) + 
      I (2 Γ^2 (Δc1 - Δp) + 
         8 (Δ + Δc1)^2 (Δ + Δp) + 
         8 (Δ + Δc2) (Δ + Δp)^2 + 8 (Δ + Δp)^3 - 
         2 (Δ + Δc2) Ωc1^2 - 2 (Δ + Δp) Ωc1^2 + 
         2 (Δ + Δc1) (-4 (Δ + Δc2) (Δ + Δp) - 
            8 (Δ + Δp)^2 + Ωc1^2) - 
         2 (Δ + Δp) Ωc2^2 + 
         I Γ (4 (Δ + Δc1)^2 + 4 (Δ + Δc2) (Δ + Δp) + 8 (Δ + Δp)^2 - 
            4 (Δ + Δc1) (Δ + Δc2 + 
               3 (Δ + Δp)) - Ωc1^2 - Ωc2^2)));

parameterRules =  {Ωc1 -> 4, Ωc2 -> .1, Γ -> 1,  
                   Δc1 -> 0, Δs -> 0, Δc2 -> 0, 
                   z -> 1, γ -> 0, ϕ -> 0, W -> 10};

(*Analytic Integration:*)
DL4lvldopplerPtoPΔ = Integrate[ expr, {Δ, -∞, ∞}] // Normal // Simplify;
analyticalSol = DL4lvldopplerPtoPΔ /. parameterRules;


(*Numeric Integration:*)
numericallyIntegraled = expr /. parameterRules // Simplify;
f[Δp_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[numericallyIntegraled, {Δ, -∞, ∞}];


(*Plotting real and imag parts of (Analytic and Numeric):*)
Plot[{Re[ComplexExpand[f[Δp]]], 
      Re[ComplexExpand[analyticalSol]]}, {Δp, -10, 10}, 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {"Δp", 
    "Im[expr]: Numeric Vs Analytic"}}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, BaseStyle -> 12
]
Plot[{Im[ComplexExpand[f[Δp]]], 
      Im[ComplexExpand[analyticalSol]]}, {Δp, -10, 10}, 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {"Δp", 
    "Re[expr]: Numeric Vs Analytic"}}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, BaseStyle -> 12, PlotRange -> All
]
```

One thing to note is that I tweaked the conditional expression to just be a normal expression. If I don't do this, I cannot obtain a plot anymore, and if I try to look at my analytic expression, I get the form:

```
Cell[CellGroupData[{Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{"Simplify", "[", 
  RowBox[{
   RowBox[{"Re", "[", 
    RowBox[{"ComplexExpand", "[", "analyticalSol", "]"}], "]"}], ",", 
   " ", 
   RowBox[{"Element", "[", 
    RowBox[{"Δp", ",", " ", "Reals"}], "]"}]}], 
  "]"}]], "Input",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.799702119453383*^9, 3.799702156106647*^9}, {
  3.7997022143955765`*^9, 3.7997022256841283`*^9}},
 CellLabel->"In[97]:="],

Cell[BoxData["Undefined"], "Output",
 CellChangeTimes->{
  3.7997020940830355`*^9, 3.799702157040344*^9, {
   3.7997022211933966`*^9, 3.799702226293498*^9}},
 CellLabel->"Out[97]="]
}, Open  ]]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

**EDIT:** Thanks to the user @MarcoB, I've made a correction to this question. My primary interest is getting a correct, fully symbolic solution for this integral. The numerics I'm performing is really just a check for the analytic integration was performed accurately. So while I know that I can fix the plot (by plugging in the parameters used for the plot before performing the analytic integration), it really prevents me from obtaining my main goal: an accurate, fully-symbolic integration of the expression.

**EDIT2:** @CATrevillian suggested that the analytic integration is correct - but by dropping the Conditional Form of the expression I'm getting an incorrect result. Here's an example I accidentally found that directly plots this Conditional Expression (without doing the suspicious step of removing the conditional statement). In this example there is still a disagreement with the numerical solution, but now a slightly different disagreement. Here is the code:

```
expr = 1/W Sqrt[Log[2]/\[Pi]] 1/(
     1 + (Δ/W)^2) (I (-4 (Δ + Δc1)^2 + 
          4 (Δ + Δc1) (Δ + Δc2) + 
          2 \[Gamma] (Γ + 
             2 I (-Δ + Δc1 - Δc2 - Δp)) + 
          2 I Γ (Δc1 - Δp) + 8 (Δ + Δc1) (Δ + Δp) - 
          4 (Δ + Δc2) (Δ + Δp) - 
          4 (Δ + Δp)^2 + Ωc2^2))/(2 \[Gamma] (Γ + 
           2 I (-Δ + Δc1 - Δc2 - Δp)) (Γ - 
           2 I (Δ + Δp)) + 
        I (2 Γ^2 (Δc1 - Δp) + 8 (Δ + Δc1)^2 (Δ + Δp) + 
           8 (Δ + Δc2) (Δ + Δp)^2 + 8 (Δ + Δp)^3 - 
           2 (Δ + Δc2) Ωc1^2 - 
           2 (Δ + Δp) Ωc1^2 + 2 (Δ + Δc1) (-4 (Δ + Δc2) (Δ + Δp) - 
              8 (Δ + Δp)^2 + Ωc1^2) - 
           2 (Δ + Δp) Ωc2^2 + I Γ (4 (Δ + Δc1)^2 + 
              4 (Δ + Δc2) (Δ + Δp) + 8 (Δ + Δp)^2 - 
              4 (Δ + Δc1) (Δ + Δc2 + 3 (Δ + Δp)) - Ωc1^2 - Ωc2^2))) /. { Δc1 -> 0, Δs -> 0, Δc2 -> 0, γ -> 0, Γ -> 1}; // Simplify

parameterRules =  {Ωc1 -> 4, Ωc2 -> .1, Γ -> 1,  Δc1 -> 0, Δs -> 
    0, Δc2 -> 0, z -> 1, γ -> 0, ϕ -> 0, W -> 10};

(*Analytic Integration:*)
DL4lvldopplerPtoPΔ = 
  Integrate[ expr, {Δ, -∞, ∞}, 
    Assumptions -> {Δp ∈ Reals, Ωc1 ∈ Reals, Ωc2 ∈ Reals, 
       Γ ∈ Reals,  Δc1 ∈ Reals, Δs ∈ Reals, Δc2 ∈ Reals, 
      z ∈ Reals, γ ∈ Reals, ϕ ∈ Reals, W ∈ Reals}] // Simplify;
analyticalSol = DL4lvldopplerPtoPΔ /. parameterRules;

(*Numeric Integration:*)
numericallyIntegraled = expr /. parameterRules // Simplify;
f[Δp_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[numericallyIntegraled, {Δ, -∞, ∞}];


(*Plotting real and imag parts of (Analytic and Numeric):*)
Plot[{Re[ComplexExpand[f[Δp]]], 
      Re[ComplexExpand[analyticalSol]]}, {Δp, -10, 10}, 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, 
                {"Δp", "Re[expr]: Numeric Vs Analytic"}}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, BaseStyle -> 12
]

Plot[{Im[ComplexExpand[f[Δp]]], 
      Im[ComplexExpand[analyticalSol]]}, {Δp, -10, 10}, 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, 
                {"Δp", "Im[expr]: Numeric Vs Analytic"}}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, BaseStyle -> 12, PlotRange -> All
]
```

And it looks like this:

[image: imaginary parts of the analytical vs. numeric integrals of the new expression]

Which now is in agreement with the numerics for half of the domain of $\Delta_p$. This suggests to me that something is going wrong in the symbolic integration.

Comment: You tweaked the results from the fully symbolic integrate? How can you be sure that this is not where the errors begin to occur?

Comment: I answered that at the bottom. If you leave it as a conditional expression, it still cannot find the solution and thinks its "undefined."  (Even though the numeric solution can easily solve it).

Comment: I don’t follow. You obtain a fully symbolic integration. You show this, it is a conditional, yes, but otherwise fully symbolic. If you expect an exact form, how do you have confidence you can find this? Then you tweak it, why—for what reason? And how do you know that the tweaks you employ do not cause the discrepancies you see?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Your employment of `Normal` here only applies to the expression in the first argument. I’ll see if I can show you how to fix this :)

Comment: @CATrevillian  Thanks a lot for your help.  This code was run on Mathematica 11.3.

Comment: @CATrevillian, Okay so if I'm understanding correctly, you think that the fact that I can't plot this solution (without forcing it to be in a "normal form") is because Mathematica can't find a closed-form-solution for the set of inputs in the parameter space I'm interested in?

Comment: Clearly, Mathematica can solve this in both a symbolic and numerical form--the question is if there exists an exact solution as you wish to find. When you apply the parameter rules you define, you'll find that the conditions are `False` for all values of `Δp` greater or less than 0, with `Indeterminate` result at 0. You must also realize that you are, effectively, performing two inequivalent `Integrate` operations, If you do not sub in parameter values as @MarcoB shows. 12.1 does no better with this. Perhaps you might try [`Rubi`](https://rulebasedintegration.org/integrationRules.html)?

Comment: @CATrevillian, if you have time, take a look at the code I added in EDIT2. It shows a plot of the symbolic integral (without using Normal[]) that disagrees with the numerical solution. I think this is a different case, and suggests there's something other issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since you end up substituting numerical values, I recommend doing that earlier rather than later. This should greatly simplify the complex task you set for `Integrate` and is likely to lead to better results. You also evaluate the integral for real values of `Δp`, so it would make sense to make `Integrate` aware of that possible simplification as well, through `Assumptions`:

```
analytical = Integrate[
    expr /. parameterRules,
    {Δ, -Infinity, Infinity},
    Assumptions -> Δp ∈ Reals
  ]

(* Out: 
-(((-1 + 200*Δp*(21*I + 2*Δp))*Sqrt[Pi*Log[2]]) /
      ((21*I + 2*Δp)*(-1601 + 200*Δp*(21*I + 2*Δp))))
*)
```

[image: analytical output of Integrate]

The numerical version is:

```
ClearAll[numerical]
numerical[dp_?NumericQ] :=
  NIntegrate[
    expr /. parameterRules /. Δp -> dp,
    {Δ, -Infinity, Infinity}
  ]
```

Checking with a random value shows that it works: `numerical[4]` returns `-0.0185615 + 0.0649662 I`.

The following plots show that the real and imaginary parts obtained through these methods are identical:

```
Plot[
   Evaluate@#[{analytical, numerical[Δp]}], {Δp, -10, 10},
   PlotStyle -> {
     Directive[Thickness[0.03], GrayLevel[0.6]],
     Directive[Thick, Darker@Orange]},
   PlotLegends -> {"analytical", "numerical"}, ImageSize -> Medium,
   Epilog -> Inset[Style[ToString@#, 18, Black], Scaled[{0.9, 0.9}]]
] & /@ {Re, Im}
```

[image: comparison of Real and Imaginary parts]

You can also plot the *differences* between the analytical and numerical expressions and  you will see that they are identical, within the numerical error to be expected with machine-precision evaluation.

Comment: Sorry! I don't think I was clear! The analytical expression (without the particular parameters) IS very important to me. I need the analytical expression in its full form. (It just so happens that I can verify that something is wrong with that analytical expression when I look at this plot!) I'll edit the question to make that more clear for everyone.

Comment: I tried cleaning up the language to use the phrase "completely-symbolic expression" instead of "analytic expression", and added a note at the end explaining that I can't plug in the parameters at an earlier point without losing the goal of getting a "completely-symbolic integral", and that the purpose of the numeric integration is simply to check if the analytic integral is accurate.

Comment: Also, I tried seeing if using "Assumptions -> Δp ∈ Reals" in the full integral would fix the issue and it didn't, unfortunately. You can assume that all the variables are real, and that all values except Δp, Δs, Δc1, and Δc2 are positive.

If you could take a look at the fully-symbolic integral it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @StevenSagona I think, perhaps, you may be making the problem more difficult than it needs to be. The solution provided by MarcoB shows that you have the correct form. Why are you concerned about the non-dependent parameters? This shows the numeric result is accurate, also. You might find `NIntegrate` will run much faster than `Integrate` and could find/plot trends much faster that way.

Comment: @CATrevillian, my goal is a correct, fully-symbolic integral. The purpose of using NIntegrate is simply to check if this symbollic integral is correct. I believe it's very standard to do numerical simulations to "check" if an analytic solution is correct, and if I simply wanted a numerical solution I would use Matlab to do it.