# Can you force Integrate[] to find a complete symbolic solution for all variables?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, parameters

(As I've asked on the [Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3697553/closed-form-solution-of-integral-with-many-free-variables) and on a related previous [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/222867/results-from-integrate-not-matching-nintegrate)), I am interested in getting a complete symbolic solution to the integral of an expression with a lot of unassigned variables. If you combine some of the variables, the integral can be reduced to the form:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\text{A} \Delta +\text{B}}{\left(\Delta ^2+W^2\right) \left(\text{C}+\text{D}\Delta  +\text{E}\Delta ^2 \right)}d\Delta$$

Mathematica claims that the solution to this integral is:

$$\frac{\pi  (\text{B}-i \text{A} W)}{W (\text{C}-W (\text{E} W+i \text{D}))} \text{if: } \Im\left(\frac{E\pm\sqrt{E^2-4 C E}}{E}\right)<0 $$

Shown as code:

```
Integrate[
 (A1 Δ + B1)/((W^2 + Δ^2) (C1 + D1 Δ + E1 Δ^2)),
 {Δ, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> {W > 0}]
```

Which returns:

```
ConditionalExpression[(π (B1 - I A1 W))/(
 W (C1 - W (I D1 + E1 W))), 
 Im[(D1 - Sqrt[D1^2 - 4 C1 E1])/E1] < 0 && 
  Im[(D1 + Sqrt[D1^2 - 4 C1 E1])/E1] < 0 && Re[W] > 0]
```

Mathematica generates a conditional-expression, but doesn't specify if this is a "full" answer. For instance what if we consider the integral under the domain of parameters with the opposite inequalities: $\Im\left(\frac{E\pm\sqrt{E^2-4 C E}}{E}\right)>0$? Is there a solution in this domain of parameters?

I can try to force Mathematica to spit out an answer under different conditions. For example:

```
Integrate[
 (A1 Δ + B1)/((W^2 + Δ^2) (C1 + D1 Δ + E1 Δ^2)),
 {Δ, -∞, ∞}, 
 Assumptions -> {W > 0, Im[(D1 - Sqrt[D1^2 - 4 C1 E1])/E1] > 0, 
   Im[(D1 + Sqrt[D1^2 - 4 C1 E1])/E1] < 0}]
```

I can get another symbolic answer for this new parameter space:

$$\frac{i \pi  \left(\text{A1} D W+(-i) \text{B1} \sqrt{D^2-4 C E}-2 \text{B1} E W\right)}{W \sqrt{D^2-4 C E} \left(C+W \left(E W+i \sqrt{D^2-4 C E}\right)\right)}$$

Is there an option to do this automatically and generate a solution for the entire set of possible combinations in the domain space? I'm honestly pretty surprised that it does not automatically return a combined piece-wise function with these different integrated results.

Answer (score 5):

This is what `GenerateConditions`$\to$`All` is supposedly supposed to do, but I find it doesn't usually work. From the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GenerateConditions.html) `GenerateConditions`$\to$`All` should

> return all possible answers using `Piecewise`

But I find it doesn't work for your integral and practically no, what you seek is unfortunately not possible. Straight from the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html) on `Integrate` (Under Options, Assumptions)

> By default, conditions are generated on parameters that guarantee convergence
>
> ...
>
> Manually specify `Assumptions` to test values outside the automatically generated conditions